# Visual Customization Issue in Flutter Stepper: I Can't Achieve the Desired Customization and I'm Experiencing Visual Errors

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a stepper to display some modules in my app. As you can see, I use what Flutter offers for these cases, the issue is that I wanted to put the content in the title to have the effect that the step numbers are in the center of the content since I couldn't do it that way by pasting the content in the content. But this visual effect happens and I can't correct it. my code is this

```
Step(
state: StepState.disabled,
title: _StepContent(
title: e.title,
subTitle: e.subTitle,
imageUrl: e.file.url,
>                                       ),
content: Align(
alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
child: SizedBox(height: 0),
>                                       ),
>                                     ),
```

[image]

I wanted to make an effect something like this

[image]